# href target to a new website at some certain div id of that new website

Tags: php, jquery, html

is it possible to create a link that when clicked would open a new tab with a certain web page and slide down to a certain div id of that new page, such as comments, knowing div id

```
 <a href="somepage.php" target="_blank">click here</a>
```

without having any administrative role on that certain website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the fragment identifier of the URL to the div's ID:

```
<a href="somepage.php#divID" target="_blank">click here</a>
```

It's not sliding down, but the browser will put the element in the view. The element must exist on page load though.

Comment: Is it posible to send a GET parameter too, like: `<a href="somepage.php#divID?par=1" target="_blank">click here</a>`?

Comment: @mirkobrankovic: Sure, but it has to come before the fragment identifier: `somepage.php?par=1#divID`. Wikpedia explains the structure of an URI: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme#Generic_syntax.

Comment: great thx :D working like a charm now :) thx for quick answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="somepage.php#some_anchor" target="_blank">click here</a>
```

?